# Is Continuous Function Lebesgue / Borel Measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable

Proof: for $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $E=(a,\infty)$ is an open set, because $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(E)$ is open too or:

$$f^{-1}(E)=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x)>a\}$$

And $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, why conclude we that it is Lebesgue measurable and not Borel?

Comment: Inverse image of Borel set is  a Borel set. Inverse image of Borel set is  a Lebesgue measurable set. Inverse image of Lebesgue measurable set need not be  a Borel set. Inverse image of Lebesgue measurable set need not be  a Lebesgue measurable set.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy all are referring to a continuous function I assume? if $f$ is continuous so the inverse of an open set (Borel) is Borel set and therfore Lebesgue measurable set?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that the fuction is continuous. Not only is the inverse image of an open set a Borel set, the inverse image of any Borel set is also a Borel  set.

Comment: Note that every Borel set is Lebesgue m'ble but the converse is not true.